# SQLite - check if any field has a 1 on each column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following query:

```
SELECT c.danhoEstetico, c.danhoDirecto
FROM conceptos c
INNER JOIN materialesconceptos mc ON mc.idConcepto = c.idConcepto
INNER JOIN materiales m ON m.idMaterial = mc.idMaterial
WHERE m.idMaterial IN (4,11,11)
```

Which yields the following result (for example):

```
danhoEstetico | danhoDirecto
1             | 0
1             | 0
0             | 0
0             | 0
```

I need to make a query that gives me if any of the items in each column has a 1, like an OR among all the fields in the same column, with an output like:

```
danhoEstetico | danhoDirecto
1             | 0
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE c.danhoEstetico WHEN c.danhoEstetico=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS de,
SUM(CASE c.danhoDirecto WHEN c.danhoDirecto=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dd
FROM conceptos c INNER JOIN materialesconceptos mc ON mc.idConcepto = c.idConcepto
INNER JOIN materiales m ON m.idMaterial = mc.idMaterial
WHERE m.idMaterial IN (4,11,11)
```

Which, for some reason, yields:

```
danhoEstetico | danhoDirecto
4             | 4
```

Any hint on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the largest value in each column, use `MAX` instead of `SUM`.

Comment: Flagged for deletion because getting the largest value has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: `OR` on binary 0/1 values is the same as `MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I misread the question.  This solution checks that *every* row in a column is 1, rather than *any* row.  I recommend CL's answer, but I will leave this answer here because it explains a problem with the `CASE` statement in the question.

You should be using `CASE` without a base expression:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN c.danhoEstetico=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS de,
SUM(CASE WHEN c.danhoDirecto=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS dd
FROM conceptos c INNER JOIN materialesconceptos mc ON 
    mc.idConcepto = c.idConcepto
INNER JOIN materiales m ON m.idMaterial = mc.idMaterial
WHERE m.idMaterial IN (4,11,11)
```

From [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> In a CASE with a base expression, the base expression is evaluated
>   just once and the result is compared against the evaluation of each
>   WHEN expression from left to right. The result of the CASE expression
>   is the evaluation of the THEN expression that corresponds to the first
>   WHEN expression for which the comparison is true...

In your statement as written, the `case` statement always evaluated to `1` when the column was `1` and `0` when the column was `0`.  Thus, they always matched, and the sum was always the number of rows.

**Update:** now how do you actually turn this into the result you want?  Here is one way:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN c.danhoEstetico=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(1) AS de,
SUM(CASE WHEN c.danhoDirecto=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(1)  AS dd
FROM conceptos c INNER JOIN materialesconceptos mc ON 
    mc.idConcepto = c.idConcepto
INNER JOIN materiales m ON m.idMaterial = mc.idMaterial
WHERE m.idMaterial IN (4,11,11)
```

This takes advantage of integer arithmetic.  The division will result in a value < 1 if not all rows in a column are one, and a value less than one will show as zero.

Comment: That way I get 2, 2 as result

Comment: @manutenfruits, see the update.  My initial answer just explained why the `case` statement was not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct 
       c.danhoEstetico, c.danhoDirecto
 FROM conceptos c
 INNER JOIN materialesconceptos mc ON mc.idConcepto = c.idConcepto
 INNER JOIN materiales m ON m.idMaterial = mc.idMaterial
where 1 in (c.danhoEstetico , c.danhoDirecto)
```